# Webpage bouncing vertically when spinner is visible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

Content around the spinner (sidebar, previous paginated items) seem to bounce up and down, vertically. Issue disappears when the spinner is not active.

If I scroll **almost** to the end (half the height of the spinner) this won't happen, its only when I scroll so far the entire spinner is visible that the page 'bounces'.

I have this code, which shows a spinner when profiles are loading or paginating:

```
{(this.state.profilesLoading || this.state.profilesPaginating) && (<div className="flex justify-center items-center h-full">
    <div className="animate-spin rounded-full h-32 w-32 border-b-2 border-gray-900"></div>
</div>)}
```

If I remove the inner div, no more bounce:

```
{(this.state.profilesLoading || this.state.profilesPaginating) && (<div className="flex justify-center items-center h-full">
    Loading...
</div>)}
```

Unsure if this is a React bug with evaluating conditional checks and its re-render logic, Tailwind bug with its animations, or JavaScript bug in general?

Comment: Any chance of getting a [mcve]?  For what it's worth, it sounds much more likely to be a CSS/layout issue than anything relating to React...

Comment: As @AlexanderNied commented, we'll need more to go on. I just tried this locally with tailwind and it works fine so we need the context around the loading spinner that could be effecting it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try and reproduce this in tailwind playground to begin with and update with a link.